# How to execute tcl scripts in tchsh with arguments

Tags: shell, tcl, tclsh

Normally I invoke my tcl script under shell like this.

```
> tclsh8.5 mytest.tcl -opt1 foo -opt2 bar
```

In case need to launch gdb to debug due to some modules implemented in C++. I have to launch tclsh via gdb. So the question is how to execute my script in tcl sh with arguments.

I need something like:

```
tclsh> run mytest.tcl -opt1 foo -opt2 bar
```

Using exec is not ideal as it folks another process and losses my breakpoints settings.

```
tclsh> exec mytest.tcl -opt1 foo -opt2 bar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would think something like the following should work for you:

```
set argv [list -opt1 foo -opt2 bar]
set argc 4
source mytest.tcl
```

So set argv and argc to get the arguments correct and then just source in your Tcl code to execute.

Alternatively the gdb run command allows you to pass command line arguments to the executable to be debugged.  So if your debugging tclsh then the what is the problem with the run command as follows?

```
run mytest.tcl -opt1 foo -opt2 bar
```

For example under cygwin I'm able to do the following:

```
$ tclsh test.tcl
This is a test
$ gdb -q tclsh.exe
(no debugging symbols found)
(gdb) run test.tcl
Starting program: /usr/bin/tclsh.exe test.tcl
```

Comment: "run mytest.tcl -opt1 foo ..." looks great. How do I exactly do this in gdb? 

1. > gdb tclsh
2. (enter tclsh), press ctrl-C to switch to gdb shell
3. (gdb) break myCppCode.cc:123 (make bp pending on future lib loaded)
4. (gdb) continue
5. start it from beginning? (y or n) What should I do here? If choose "yes", then it won't stop at breakpoint. If choose "no", it switch back to tclsh and do nothing. Is there anything missed?

Comment: when you run tclsh under gdb you should get the standard (gdb) command prompt.  You should be able to set breakpoints here and then run the program with the specified arguments.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running tclsh within a gdb session and set arguments, you do something like this (`$` is a shell prompt, `(gdb)` is a gdb prompt, and I've left out all the messages that get printed by gdb):

```
$ gdb tclsh
(gdb) set args mytest.tcl -opt1 foo -opt2 bar
(gdb) ... set some breakpoints ...
(gdb) run
```

You might also need `set env FOO=bar` to set up the environment, depending on what is going on in your script. Tcl's own build files use techniques like this to pass in arguments when debugging the running of the test suite.

Comment: Ah, I didn't set env FOO=bar. That's way my breakpoints were never triggered since it's attaching to the release version.

Answer (score 0):

Why do not just run

```
gdb --args tclsh8.5 mytest.tcl -opt1 foo -opt2 bar
```

when you need to debug your application?

Comment: Because I need to set breakpoints, or it will just execute and terminate directly.

Comment: gdb will start in interactive mode. You can set your breakpoints and continue with `run` command.